# How to set variables in a loop with oracle?

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, setvalue

I have a loop and a variable `v_rownum` and I want to set value for it:

```
        FOR donvi_rows IN v_donvi
        LOOP
            DECLARE
               v_rownum number;
            SELECT r
            INTO v_rownum
            FROM
            (SELECT ROWNUM AS r, k.Id
            FROM don_vi k
            WHERE k.ParentId = 1 )
            WHERE Id = donvi_rows.Id;

        END LOOP;
```

But it throw a exception:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.
```

I'm currently studying Oracle. I don't know much about it. Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Oracle you need to declare all your variables at the top of the block, before the `BEGIN`:

```
DECLARE
    ... variable declarations
BEGIN
    ... program logic
END;
```

Your code should go something like this:

```
DECLARE 
    v_rownum number;
    CURSOR v_donvi IS
      SELECT * FROM whatever;
    ... any other declarations
BEGIN
    FOR donvi_rows IN v_donvi
    LOOP
        SELECT r
          INTO v_rownum
          FROM (
            SELECT ROWNUM AS r, k.Id
            FROM don_vi k
            WHERE k.ParentId = 1
          )
          WHERE Id = donvi_rows.Id;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your studying?;)
I use this:

```
DECLARE
    q NUMBER;
        BEGIN
            q := &x;
            for x IN 1 .. q LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    FOR donvi_rows IN v_donvi
    LOOP
        DECLARE
           v_rownum number;
        BEGIN
           SELECT r
           INTO v_rownum
           FROM
           (SELECT ROWNUM AS r, k.Id
           FROM don_vi k
           WHERE k.ParentId = 1 )
           WHERE Id = donvi_rows.Id;
        END;
    END LOOP;
```